# Next.js `getLayout` function is not called

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a `layout.jsx` like below:

```
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google';
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] });
import { Analytics } from '@vercel/analytics/react';
import Bootstrap from '../pages/components/bootstrap';
import Navbar from '../pages/components/Navbar';

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body className={inter.className + ' container'}>
        <Bootstrap></Bootstrap>
        <Navbar></Navbar>
        {children}
        <Analytics />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

and have `pages/news.tsx` like below:

```
import DataClient from '../lib/data/DataClient';
import NewsItem from './components/NewsItem';
import RssFeedItem from '../lib/data/models/RSSFeedItem';
import RootLayout from './components/layout';

type NewsProps = {
  rssFeeds: RssFeedItem[];
};

export default function News({ rssFeeds }: NewsProps) {
  const items = rssFeeds.map((item) => {
    return <NewsItem key={item.id} item={item}></NewsItem>;
  });
  return <div>{items}</div>;
}

News.getLayout = function getLayout(page) {
  console.log('getlayout');
  return <RootLayout>{page}</RootLayout>;
};

export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const dataClient = new DataClient();
  const limit = 50;
  const skip = 0;
  const rssFeeds = await dataClient.getRssFeedItems(limit, skip);

  // Convert isoDate properties to serializable format (string)
  const rssFeedsSerialized = rssFeeds.map((feed) => ({
    ...feed,
    isoDate: feed.isoDate.toISOString(),
    created_at: feed.created_at.toISOString(),
    updated_at: feed.updated_at.toISOString()
  }));

  return {
    props: {
      rssFeeds: rssFeedsSerialized
    }
  };
};
```

But `News.getLayout` is not getting fired and the `/news` url does not show the `Navbar` component in the `RootLayout`. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getLayout` function is part of what Next.js calls [Per-Page Layouts](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#per-page-layouts), and the function doesn't get called automatically. You have to call it yourself in `_app.js`:

```js
// pages/_app.js

import Layout from "./_layout";

export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout;
  if (getLayout) {
    return getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />);
  }
  // You could wrap pages with no getLayout with a global layout if you want
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```